# Powershell: Applying filters to records returned from Resolve-DnsName

Tags: powershell

After reading the docs, I thought that I could use the `type` parameter to filter the records that should be returned from the cmdlet. So, I expected that asking for the MX record type from a name associated only with the A record should return nothing. However, that is not what's happening here. For instance, both these cmdlets return the same thing:

```bash
> Resolve-DnsName subdomain.domain.com
Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
subdomain.domain.com           CNAME  161   Answer     other.domain.com

> Resolve-DnsName subdomain.domain.com -Type MX

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
subdomain.domain.com           CNAME  161   Answer     other.domain.com
```

Is this behaviour correct? I mean, if there are no MX records associated with the name `subdomain.domain.com`, then shouldn't the cmdlet return nothing?

Thanks.

Comment: From the docs,`-Type`  *Specifies the DNS query type that is to be issued. By default the type is A_AAAA, the A and AAAA types will both be queried*

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm getting cname in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some [digging and poking/asking around](https://superuser.com/questions/1762667/dns-why-does-the-server-return-a-cname-record-when-asked-for-an-mx), it seems like this is the correct behavior for CNAME records requests:

Answer (score 0):

Managed to reproduce the same behavior, but this workaround should do.

```
Resolve-DnsName domain.com -Type MX | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "MX"}
```

Then you can create logic around that